# int to char cast, strange behavior

Tags: c, char, printf, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

Consider the following:

```c
unsigned int  i1 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
unsigned char c1 = i1;
char          c2 = i1;

printf("%x\n", i1);       // 0xFFFFFFFF as expected
printf("%x\n", c1);       // 0xFF as expected
printf("%x\n", c2);       // 0xFFFFFFFF ????
printf("%d\n", c1 == c2); // false ????
```

I know, one should not assign an `int` to a `char`. Anyway, look how `c2` seems to be storing more than a byte. What I expected was a copy of the "less significant byte" of `n1` into `c2`. Am I wrong to assume this? Is there no copy at all? Why does the behavior of `unsigned char` differs from `char`?

---

I actually found this in a very concrete situation while using [gethostbyname()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html). It returns a struct which contains a field `char *h_addr` storing an ipv4 address (four 8 bit long numbers). I wanted to print the ip address as numbers but got abnormally large results.

---

I know a workaround, masking with `i1 & 0xFF` works but I would like to understand the issue.

Comment: What are n1, n2, and n3?  I see i1 (not n1).

Comment: When passed to `printf` `char` is getting converted to `int`.

Comment: You learned to be very, very careful when mixing signed and unsigned values.  I suspect if you enable all compiler warnings, you'll get a good number of them.

Comment: "I know, one should not assign an int to a char" - more things to unlearn. You do this all the time

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The wording here is unclear. It is okay *per se* to assign an `int` type to a `char`, but it is not generally okay to assign an `int` value to a `char` if it may be outside the values representable in a `char`, as it is not portable (is not fully defined by the C standard, does not yield strictly conforming code, and could trap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char`.

After this assignment

```
char          c2 = n1;
```

Note: It seems there is a typo and you mean

```
char          c2 = i1;
```

the variable c2 has the value `0xff` that is `-1`.

In this call

```
printf("%x\n", c2);
```

the argument expression `c2` is converted to the type `int` propagating the sign bit due to the integer promotions. And this value is outputted according to the format `%x`.

Pay attention to that you need to write

```
printf( "%x\n",( unsigned int ) c2 );
```

because the conversion specifier `x` expects an object of the type `unsigned int`.

If you want to get the expected by you result you need output the objects as objects of character types using conversion modifier `hh`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int  i1 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    unsigned char c1 = n1;
    char          c2 = n1;

    printf( "%x\n", i1 );
    printf( "%hhx\n", c1 );
    printf( "%hhx\n", c2 );
}
```

The program output is

```
ffffffff
ff
ff
```

Also it seems you made a typo and wrote

```
printf("%d\n", n3 == n2);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d\n", c1 == c2);
```

If so then again the operands of the comparison operator are implicitly converted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions. As the operand `c1` has the type `unsigned char` then it is converted to the value `0x000000FF` while the operand `c2` as it stores a negative value is converted to the value `0xFFFFFFFF`. So the result values are not equal to each other.